# Hide action bar when I click on Edittext

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-edittext

guys!
I write a simple notepad and have a little question to you. I need to hide actionbar when I click on EditText form. For example, I want to write some text, click on EditText form, then I get a keyboard. After getting keyboard I need to hide action Bar. If you use iA Writer for android you know what I talking about.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you add some of your code

Comment: You could change your ActionBar into the Toolbar, and then simply set the visibility of Tooblar to Invisible whenever you want. To read more about Toolbar, check here https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html.

Comment: Why don't you OnEditorActionListener to hide your action bar , simply  <activity>.getActionBar().hide() inside onEditorAction() call back

Answer (score 0):

Just add a listener on your EditText :

```
mEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {                     
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        // Do some stuff
    }
});
```

And then you can use this two methods if you use ActionBar :

```
getActionbar().hide();
getActionbar().show();
```

Or you can use this two methos if you use Toolbar

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
getSupportActionBar().show();
```